# Android: ksoap2 fails with NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, ksoap

There is an application that uses ksoap2 to communicate with a WebService using SOAP.

I have a report of it failing in a Samsung Galaxy Stratosphere with the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject.getPropertyAsString
```

Android version: 2.3.6.
Ksoap version: 3.0.0-RC.4

The problem is that I cannot reproduce the failure in any other device, including Androids 2.1, 2.3, 4.0... etc. Ksoap library is bundled with the Apk, which makes me think that the Stratosphere is loading the library from some other source.

Is there a way to find who is the culprit? I tried to print the jar file location of the offending class, but each method fails, getProtectionDomain() returns null as well as getResource() variants.

Even if I find that Android is loading the library from somewhere else, how to force it load the one in my Apk?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9231654/android-on-some-devices-i-get-nosuchmethoderror-when-calling-method-of-linked-l

Comment: That question doesn't provide an answer other than what I already know

Comment: its a reference tats y its added as a comment not an answer.